# Jquery Selector specific elements of a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that I'm building that looks something like this:

```
<ul id="myUl">
    <li><span>li #1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="myContent">
                    <a href="" name="myLink">clickMe!</a>
                </div>
            </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, i'd like to define a click handler for the `<a>` tag of the `ul` with the id of `"myUl".`

I tried something like a css selector like:

```
$('ul[id="myUl] a').on('click', do stuff!);
```

or

`$('ul[id="myUl] > a').on('click', do stuff!);` //this doesn't work because `a` is not a direct child of `ul`.

What's the correct way of handeling clicks of just the `a` element of this specific `ul`?

Comment: Note that you're missing the closing `</ul>` for the nested `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
$('#myUl').on('click', 'a', do stuff!);
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this.

```
$('#myUl a').on('click', your_func);
```

Notice I didn't use the `>`, which restricts you to direct descendants *(children)* of the `ul`.

Or you can do it like this.

```
$('#myUl').on('click', 'a', your_func);
```

The difference is that this binds the handler to the UL, but only triggers it when the `a` is clicked. The first example binds directly to the `a`.

Comment: The second one is technically accurate

Comment: @frshca: What do you mean? They're equally accurate.

Comment: Yes they both work, but the second method is preferred just because it is delegating the event handler. So if the OP wants to have multiple anchors, the second method will attach only one event handler but delegate the event (click) to the anchors.

Comment: @frshca: The second method is preferred in those situations where a developer decides it would be preferable. There's nothing wrong with a non-delegated approach. It seems a bit narrow to suggest that the second is preferred just because it delegates the handler.

Comment: agree to disagree I guess. Hierarchical selectors such as the first one, in my opinion (and jQuery's opinion), will give you a performance hit. Yes we are talking about one selector here so you will probably never notice the difference, but why wouldn't you just perform best practices? Please read http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance , this is covered in the last paragraph.

Comment: @frshca: You've misunderstood that section, and the last paragraph. It is not discussing direct binding vs delegated binding. It is discussing globally bound delegates *(the way `.live()` works)* vs more locally bound delegates *(binding as close to the elements as possible)*. The last paragraph specifically deals with simple vs complex selectors as pertaining to the selector used for delegation. Hierarchical selectors will be more expensive than selectors that don't require traversal. jQuery's event delegation is extremely generalized, and therefore somewhat expensive. So these tips can help.

Comment: ...and by "globally bound", I mean binding to an element that encompasses all elements on the page, like `document` or `body`.

Comment: I see what jQuery and you are saying, I did misinterpret the meaning. I guess I would just use the second one because the selector is faster than the first and so that listener will be attached quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `>` in the selector makes it more specific than it needs to be. If you take it out, then it'll work for any child elements (at any level) rather than direct children.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#myUl a').click(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul#myUl a').on('click', do stuff!);
```

or

```
$('ul[id="myUl"] a').on('click', do stuff!);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You missing " in `$('ul[id="myUl"] a').on('click', do stuff!);` and in `$('ul[id="myUl"] > a').on('click', do stuff!);` 
but you can directly use id of element as a selector:

`$('#myUl a').on('click', handler function);`

Answer (score 1):

your missing a quote, but try this instead:

```
$('#myUl a').on('click', function(){alert('do stuff!')});
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres also the context you can specify within a selector

```
$('a','#myUl').click
//  This is equivelant to $('#myUl').find('a')
//  So this finds all descendant anchor tags of #myUl
```